# Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm trying to run command " rake db:test:prepare" in 6.2 of Rails Tutorial book. And then I had this problem

I have already run " gem install bundler". But it wasn't work. After I check version in path /home/myname/.rvm/gems. T got version of Ruby is 2.6.3

```
Gemfile:  
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.3'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8', '>= 3.8.2'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
# group :production do
#   gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
#   gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
# end
```

How can i fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting this same issue.  Seems to be something weird going on with 2.6.3's bundler.  2.6.1 for instance doesn't have this error.

Answer (score 1):

This usually comes up when the specified ruby version is not installed. To install using rvm run:

```
rvm install ruby-2.6.3
```

If you suspect it's already installed, then you may need to tell rvm to use the specific version, as it might default to another version (in this case 2.5.1). To do that run:

```
rvm --default use ruby-2.6.3
```

If it's not installed, the above command will throw a relevant error.

Comment: Make sure you have got rvm.
Run the below command to enable rvm (Ruby Version Manager (RVM))
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable